# Compare foreign keys - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm presented with this problem:

Stock within a warehouse is represented by rows in the following database table:

```
CREATE TABLE stock (
  id SERIAL,
  product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES products ( id ),
  location_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES locations ( id ),
  package_id integer REFERENCES packages ( id ),
  qty integer
);
```

Any products that are within the same package must, given the
    constraints of physics, be present at the same location within the
    warehouse.  Unfortunately, due to bugs in the application layer, some
    database rows violate this constraint.

There are approximately two million rows in the stock table.

Write a database query to identify the affected rows.

Now, I understand that `product_id` is a foreign key, as well as `location_id` and `package_id` on `stock` table, but somehow I'm very confused on how to achieve this.

One thing I've thought, is to compare packages with products, but I'm still stuck, because the thing is, when the package is the same on product, then their location should be the same. So, I'm not seeing the big picture yet.

I'm a little thick on this one, lol, any ideas on how to approach it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The query should find packages identified by pairs `(product_id, package_id)` having more than one `location_id`:

```
select product_id, package_id, count(distinct location_id)
from stock
group by product_id, package_id
having count(distinct location_id) > 1
```

> Unfortunately, due to bugs in the application layer, some database rows violate this constraint.

No. Unfortunately, the model is incorrect. Locations should be referenced by packages, not by stock.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, yes, indeed, that was quite confusing.